# how to avoid this "duplicate entry for key"

Tags: php, mysql

I've set email field as unique, when ever I insert values it is giving that mysql error "duplicate entry for key", but I want to validate email as unique without getting that error, what is the solution for this ???

Comment: is that email already there in db

Comment: Check if the value for the email already exists in database. Insert in the database only if the value for email doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error you can use ajax function and check when the value you are giving as input.
use the "field.onchange" and send the request to mysql use ajax so that you don't get the error on submitting the data .Instead you will get the error at the time when you are giving the input.

Comment: Don't need to do that exactly, you just need to check if it's already in the table and if it is return the error.

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding duplicate entry in database use `INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE_NAME`

This will avoid insertion if record with that key already exists.

Refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) for detailed syntax and options